# How to move text up using CSS when nothing is working

Tags: html, css

I want to move the text displayed at the bottom of the page slightly upwards and have tried almost everything i know and google but can't shift the text upwards to display the remaining clipped text.

Attached is a ScreenShot of the same
Please suggest that what can be done to accomplish this task
[image: Text clipped from bottom]

Comment: Please include the corresponding html and css in your post. Your question will be useless if the link breaks.

Comment: i didn't post the html css as i posted the whole site link, there anyone can access both. That's why.

Comment: Another example of why one should not use links to third party sites for code examples. The link is dead (and removed).

Comment: line-height should be considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used the following snippet and it worked fine..

```
.smallText .bmv-disclaimer {
   height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: line-height also may solve  sometimes.

Answer (score 62):

you can try

```
position: relative;
bottom: 20px;
```

but I don't see a problem on my browser (Google Chrome)

Comment: probably the problem is in firefox only

Comment: This worked for me. Looks correct in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Genius and easy solution .

Answer (score 20):

try a negative margin.

```
margin-top: -10px; /* as an example */
```

Comment: Sure it does. He asked how to move up text in CSS, and I provided a potential solution that no one had yet provided. I was even further inclined to offer the suggestion given that he hadn't accept one as a final answer. Anything else you want to waste my time with?

Comment: It will not solve in many cases.

Comment: In a <span> this may need `display: inline-block;` to work.

Answer (score 5):

```
footerText {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

you don't need to start playing with position or even layout of other elements... use this simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Your footer container is constricting the width of the inner element with an explicit width on itself, which sees the text clipped at the end and wrapped onto a new line, so change that:

```
div#fv2-footer-container {
  width: 1090px;
  ...
```

Comment: 22.0.1229.79. Have you tried loading the page and tweaking the style in Chrome's Developer Tools? That worked for me, if it works for you I'll say that the change to your CSS hasn't been applied (i.e. Chrome's sentimental caching strategy).